# python: Not able to load json data from file in a thread

Tags: json, python-3.x

So, I'm developing a Steam Account Generator (right now the GUI) and I'm stuck with a problem. I have a thread that gets generated account's `URL` and at some point, it calls a function to change the value of the `URL` in a `JSON` file containing the information about the account. When it tries to call it, I get a `JSONDecodeError`, but when I run the function to change the values alone, it works perfectly.

This thread is being run in the main `GUI` file, it's calling another py file that contains some functions (the `steam_api_gandler_rewrite` file) that calls the `changeJSONAccountValue` function in another py file.

> [Thread (In Main File) -> steam_api_handler_rewrite -> json_func]

---

### Function to load file and change values

```
import json


def changeJSONAccountValue(value, player, dict):
    with open('files/accounts.json') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp) ##<---- Loading JSON File
    for acc in data['accounts']:
        if acc['name'] == player:
            acc[dict] = value
            with open('files/accounts.json', 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2)
```

### JSON:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "wTJxMKwhc",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": null,
      "url": null
    },
    {
      "name": "notfusion1",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": null,
      "url": null
    },
    {
      "name": "wGTwZGryG",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198918939167/"
    },
    {
      "name": "KMylosPyc",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198920127567/"
    },
    {
      "name": "gsxxMULlF",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198919031061/"
    },
    {
      "name": "louuflNsD",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198919076337/"
    },
    {
      "name": "mmidDeEMt",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198918842663/"
    },
    {
      "name": "egDUDHNKg",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198920116444/"
    },
    {
      "name": "EesxgxGkI",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": null,
      "url": null
    },
    {
      "name": "fJxYKgJZj",
      "password": "",
      "isBanned": false,
      "lastBan": 0,
      "url": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198929144294/"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Torre\PycharmProjects\SteamAccGenerator\Generator\steam_api_handler_rewrite.py", line 55, in update_ban_status
    process_data(steam_player_bans_request(ids))
  File "C:\Users\Torre\PycharmProjects\SteamAccGenerator\Generator\steam_api_handler_rewrite.py", line 72, in process_data
    json_func.changeJSONAccountValue(player['VACBanned'], acc['name'], 'isBanned')
  File "C:\Users\Torre\PycharmProjects\SteamAccGenerator\Generator\json_func.py", line 107, in changeJSONAccountValue
    data = json.load(fp)
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Torre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I can't find a solution for this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's in `files/accounts.json`?

Comment: json data (account name, password, bans informations, etc)

Comment: Specifically, what are its contents? Especially the first few bytes. Please post them in the question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: As I don't see anything wrong in your JSON file can you add a try/catch and print() the json file on failure? I suspect the file is getting corrupted (changed to a none valid json format. i.e: empty, bytes). Code would be:```with open('files/accounts.json') as fp:
        output = fp.read()
        try:
            data = json.loads(output)  #<---- Loading JSON File
        except ValueError:
            print("Fail to convert output to JSON format.\nFile output: {}\n File Length: {}".format(output, len(output)))
            raise```

Comment: Same error keeps happening, how can i fix this corruption?